# Realized + Simple Past Or Past Perfect?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which Tense is correct to use with world Realised ?

e.g..

a ) I realized that I had been cheated by my friend.

b ) I realized that I was cheated by my friend.

For me both sentence construction seems correct as per context.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I had been cheated by my friend. The realization happened in the past and the cheating by your friend had happened before that, so in this case you use past perfect.

I realized I was cheated by my friend. The cheating and the realizing are happening at the same time.